# Distribuiting values from row to colum with equal name

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have the following problem:
I got data frame `df1`

```
df1<-data.frame(name=c("C","C","C","B","B","A"),T=c(1,2,4,5,6,7),
                 A=c(0,2,3,2,3,0),B=c(1,0,2,0,0,5),C=c(0,0,0,2,0,1))

  name T A B C
1    C 1 0 1 0
2    C 2 2 0 0
3    C 4 3 2 0
4    B 5 2 0 2
5    B 6 3 0 0
6    A 7 0 5 1
```

and I want to redistribute the values from column `T` to column with corresponding column name like this:

```
  name  A B C
1    C  0 1 1
2    C  2 0 2
3    C  3 2 4
4    B  2 5 2
5    B  3 6 0
6    A  7 5 1
```

I have tried:

```
df2<-df1[outer(L$names,colnames(df1), "==")]<- df$name
df2<-df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), match( df1$names, colnames(df1)))] <-df$name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second approach was really close to working:

```
df2 <- df1
df2[cbind(1:nrow(df1), match(df1$name, colnames(df1)))] <- df2$T
df2$T <- NULL
df2
#   name A B C
# 1    C 0 1 1
# 2    C 2 0 2
# 3    C 3 2 4
# 4    B 2 5 2
# 5    B 3 6 0
# 6    A 7 5 1
```

Here `df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), match( df1$names, colnames(df1)))]` gives us the entries of `df2` that need to be replaced by `df2$T`.

Comment: Pretty cool. Do you know what is the name for this kind of subsetting with a matrix?

Comment: @snoram, I don't think there is a name. Typically there is no need for `match` and instead it's just something like `df[cbind(1:3, 3:1)]`. I think a good name for it is "a nice trick".

Comment: apparently it can also be done with character vector obviating the need for `match()`: `cbind(1:nrow(df1), as.character(df1$name))` **BUT** seems to only work in matrices and not data.frames.

Comment: @snoram, note that `cbind(1:nrow(df1), as.character(df1$name))` gets coerced to a character matrix. In that case `df2[cbind(1:nrow(df1), as.character(df1$name))]` works with matrices only when the rows are also named.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mapply` and send values in parallel.

```
df2 <- data.frame(t(mapply(function(x, y, z) {
               df1[x, y] <- z
               df1[x,] },
               1:nrow(df1), df1$name, df1$T)))

df2
#  name T A B C
#1    C 1 0 1 1
#2    C 2 2 0 2
#3    C 4 3 2 4
#4    B 5 2 5 2
#5    B 6 3 6 0
#6    A 7 7 5 1
```

Here we send the row number (`1:nrow(df1)`), the column name (`df1$name`) and the value to change (`df1$T`) to update one by one.

If you don't need `T` column anymore, you can delete it

```
df2$T <- NULL
```

---

Not a big fan of global assignment operator (`<<-`) but you can also do

```
mapply(function(x, y, z) df1[x, y] <<- z, 1:nrow(df1), df1$name, df1$T)
```

which would give the same result saving few characters to type.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using `tidyverse`:

```
df1 %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>% #Creating a row ID
 gather(var, val, -c(T, name, rowid)) %>% #Tranforming the data from wide to long format
 mutate(val = ifelse(var == name, T, val)) %>% #Using the values from column "T" in appropriate places
 spread(var, val) %>% #Trasnforming the data back to wide format
 select(-T, -rowid) #Removing the redundant variables

  name A B C
1    C 0 1 1
2    C 2 0 2
3    C 3 2 4
4    B 2 5 2
5    B 3 6 0
6    A 7 5 1
```